# Admin Themes based on user role

Tags: magento2, magento-admin

is there a way to assign different user roles different admin themes? I have looked into the documentation but it seems no one thought of this issue.

Comment: in default magento there are no any way to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to achieve what you want is by adding a theme class to the document body on document ready in a custom admin theme.

Basic example:

```
var changeTheme1 = jQuery('.admin-user-account-text').text()=='user'

//change theme
if(changeTheme1){
jQuery('body').addClass('theme1');
}
```

Maybe it helps.